# Adjust bounding box in yolo format when resizing image

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I am trying to resize images but resizing images also require me to change the bounding box values.
Has this is the yolo format **x y width height**

When i resize image of certain width and height, What would be the logic to convert the normalised bound box value in format x y Width height to new values after the image in resized to temp_width and temp_height in python

Comment: `scaling_factor_width = newImageSizeWidth/oldImageSizeWidth` now just scale x coordinate of the bounding box ad width value of the bounding box with that scaling factor. Same for scale_factor_height and height and y coordinate of the bounding box. If you want to use sub-images (cropping), you will have to subtract the new x/y voordinate of the subimage position from the bounding box x/y position.

Answer (score 0):

YOLO format is indeed a bbox (aka bounding box) coordinates/data normalized.

[Here](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/), there are clear explanations how to get these data (and Pascal VOC, as well).
Below, you'll find the code to get these Yolo format data.
You will then understand that as long as you use scaled images, you've nothing to change.

Indeed, the normalized x_center, y_center, box_width and box_height coordinates of the bbox will be scaled accordingly to the images.

But if you crop them, then you'll need to retrieve the [x_topleft, y_topleft, box_width, box_height] coordinates of the bbox and normalized them with that crop_image's size.

Suppose you have a 'bbox':

```
bbox = np.array([x_topleft, y_topleft, box_width, box_height])
       
b_width = bbox[2,]
b_height = bbox[3,]
x_max = bbox[0,] + b_width
y_max = bbox[1,] + b_height

bbox[0,] = ((x_max + bbox[0,]) / 2)  / width
bbox[1,] = ((y_max + bbox[1,]) / 2)  / height
bbox[2,] = bbox[2,] / width
bbox[3,] = bbox[3,] / height
        
bobox = bbox[0,], bbox[1,], bbox[2,], bbox[3,] # normalized x_center, y_center, box_width and box_height
```